# How to create session in keycloak with the user details and no password

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have user details (username, first name, last name, (no password)) in hand in my react app and I want to create a valid session in keycloak without user needing to log-in / sign-in (basically I don't need keycloak screen).

My end goal is to get access an access_token so I can use this access_token to validate the user using the`/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` endpoint.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?